# If and else if statements C#

Tags: c#

Hi there when I type yes or no/No it doesnt do what Its supposed to do what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username:");
        String user = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Password:");
        String Pass = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Are You Sure Your User: " + user + " And Pass: " + Pass + " is correct?  Yes/No");
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "Yes" || Console.ReadLine() == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You May now close this");
        }
        else if(Console.ReadLine() == "No" || Console.ReadLine() == "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pleas Press enter");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 ? string.Join(" ", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1)) : null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `ReadLine` twice in each `if` statement. Call it once, assign the results to a string, then test that string.

Comment: Remember that each call to Console.ReadLine is executed even in if statement! Except for, of course short-circuting behaviour of || and && operators. Besides - you should provide more information - what it is supposed to be doing and what it is doing. Just "wrong" is not enough! Some info about short circuting: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Alternatively you could use `if(Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "yes")`

Answer (score 6):

You are asking for user input twice. The first `Console.ReadLine();` is what you are typing "Yes" or "No" into, however your `if`/`else if` statements are asking for input **again**.

```
Console.WriteLine("Are You Sure Your User: " + user + " And Pass: " + Pass + " is correct?  Yes/No");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "Yes" || input == "yes")
{
   Console.WriteLine("You May now close this");
}
else if(input == "No" || input == "no")
{
   Console.WriteLine("Pleas Press enter");
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 ? string.Join(" ", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1)) : null);
}
```